# Remove ComboBox 1px white border (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, windows, forms, combobox, border

I have my beautiful flat-style combobox that want to keep its 1px-white border. I want to remove it because I have created a custom item that adds a custom border.

The problem is this:

[image]

I drawn a blue label-content and grey background in order to make you see the pixel border.
That isn't a padding/margind setting (i'm sure).

This is how it's displayed with my custom item which adds a border:

[image]

And this is my goal:

[image]

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: is this WPF? Then it's Borderthickness="0" in your XAML.

Comment: I'm sorry! This is windows forms,i added it to tags thinking it was enough :)
Now i specified it on title